# How to re render Flatlist on refresh?

Tags: database, sqlite, react-native, react-native-flatlist

Can you show me how to re render Flatlist on refresh? I use SQLite database for my local database and I have two pages one for display all workers and one for create worker. How I re render automatically page for display all workers when I create new Worker (live reload/refresh)?

Answer (score -1):

Depending on the requirements of your application, the most easiest solution would be to use the get method you're using to pull data from your application as soon as the user presses the create worker button and update your data array in your state or props (preferably props). React Native will always re-render if it detects a change within the state or props.

One issue with the above method is, it will refresh for the current user, but imagine a different user is using the app too, it won't live refresh for them unless they refresh the component themselves (this could be tabbing in and out of the page).

One work around would be to use Socket.io (https://socket.io/), to build a truly real-time application, Socket.io would allow you to listen for changes from all users and send an update request to all users which in turn should refresh their applications depending on the changes.

**EDIT:**
Add the below method to your `WorkersView` class, assuming it is different from your createWorker screen then the `WorkersView` screen will update every time a user enters the screen.

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.navigation.addListener('willFocus', this.getAllWorkers);
}
```

**Note:** I would recommend using a storage system like Redux or AsyncStorage, then you can communicate information across all your screens more efficiently and effectively.

Comment: And I do not use http protocol (Server - Client) without API. I get data from my local database (SQLite). Please, show me example or image.

Comment: Hey, I made a basic example here: https://github.com/FHaisal/gosulsez-example. It doesn't include SQLite, as I've never used that DB management before, I would personally recommend NoSQL (MongoDB, Firebase, etc.). The concept is still the same, I would imagine you have a method that adds to your database and pulls from your database. So what you need to do in the `_onCreate()` method I provided, is add the methods that pull from the database and store it within your applications `state` using `SetState()`.

Comment: Here is my code: https://imgur.com/a/musrgQc. How I re render automatically page for display all workers when I create new Worker (live reload/refresh)?

Comment: Check the edit I made on the post, it should reload every time the user enters that screen, that example will only work if your ViewWorkers screen is different from your CreateWorkers screen.